# Which data structure should I be using here?

Tags: python

New programmer here. At the moment I have a dictionary for my program containing all of the years and how many total words were used in literature for each year.

What I need to do now is to also find the relative frequency for said year by looking up a specific word given by the user. The relative frequency is found by taking the amount of times the specific word was used and dividing it by the total amount of words that were used for that year.

Do I need to be making another dictionary that contains the year and the number of times the word was used in that year? Or  a different data structure entirely? I should also mention that the user provides a start and an end date.

Below is my function for the dictionary I currently have. If you have any suggestions on how to make this better also, I'm all ears!

```
yearTotal = dict()
def addTotal():
    with open('total_counts.csv') as allWords:
        readW = csv.reader(allWords, delimiter=',')
        for row in readW:
            yearTotal[row[0]] = row[1]

addTotal()
```

Comment: Where is the source of information for how many times each specific word was used?

Comment: Good on you for thinking about data structures as a new programmer.  The best answer depends on some other factors you haven't mentioned:   Is the data dynamic or static?  How big is it, and how important is performance?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 it's in another file provided to me, that I have yet to slice out.

Comment: @wim Thank you.The data is provided to me in two files both of which are static. Also the files are quite big csv files, how quickly the program runs is not a top priority for me but would probably be nice. EDIT: I'm sorry guys I have to run to work, but I'll be back later thanks for any continued help!.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't have a lot of years (may be up to few hundreds), so I would expect list and dictionary to have similar lookup time. However, dictionaries are semantically more convenient.

At the same time, within each year you probably have a lot of words, so it's better to use structure with constant (O(1)) lookup, so dict it is.

```
from collections import defaultdict

yearTotal = defaultdict(labda: defaultdict(int))

fh = open('total_counts.csv')
for year, word in csv.reader(fh, delimiter=","):
    yearTotal[year][''] += 1  # here we'll cache the number of words
    yearTotal[year][word] += 1

# ...
word = "foo"
year = "1984"
relative_frequency = float(yearTotal[year][word]) / yearTotal[year]['']
```